# reactJS - Unexpected token upon map inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I am having an error whenever I map inside a function to call data from array. you can see my code below.

```
onAddOrder = () => {
      var newOrders = this.state.orders;
      newOrders.push({
        parts: [],
        prints: {_.map(this.state.selectedOrder.prints, (print) => {
            return {
              name: {print.printMethod},
              width: {print.width},
              height: {print.height},
              colors: {print.colors}
            };
          })},
        breakdown: [{
          size: '',
          quantity: 0
        }]
      });

      this.setState({ 
        orders: newOrders 
      });
    }
```

and here is the error I have

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/dczii/Projects/dashboard/src/components/OrderForm/OrderForm.js: Unexpected token (156:18) <br />
  154 |         },<br />
  155 |         parts: [], 
> 156 |         prints: {_.map(this.state.selectedOrder.prints, (print) => {
      |                   ^
  157 |             return {
  158 |               name: {print.printMethod},
  159 |               width: {print.width},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have confused of JSX expression block `{}`. It is used between JSX tags (like `<a>{someExpression}</a>`) and you don't have to use it in plain JavaScript, if that was your intention.

I just removed curly braces and see it works:

http://goo.gl/muvzGX

Answer (score 0):

If `prints` is a function then you are just missing the some syntax:

```
prints: () => {_.map(this.state.selectedOrder.prints, (print) => {
            return {
              name: {print.printMethod},
              width: {print.width},
              height: {print.height},
              colors: {print.colors}
            };
          })},
```

At the moment, it looks like `prints` is an object and obviously the dot is not valid on the key-side of an object literal (`{_.`)

Comment: actually the prints is an object that contains array of data